# Women's bikes/WSD tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

After seeing this question, I realized we've had a few questions about fitting and finding bikes for women. Have created a [womens-bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/womens-bikes) tag.

Before we start applying this to older questions, can anyone think of a better tag name, or are we good with this one?

I'd personally prefer something that doesn't imply that women's bikes are the exception to the rule. And "women-specific-design", [as has been pointed out](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/what-does-wsd-mean-relating-to-mountain-bikes), is a term for Trek bikes.

---

Edit:

Based on comments below, I've retagged the three questions previously tagged as womens-bikes to [women-specific](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women-specific). Please, everybody feel free to retag other questions as appropriate. That would include bikes, clothing, and other issues. Have linked to this page from the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

why do you need the `-bikes` part on a site called bicycles.stackexchange.com?

Perhaps [womens](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/womens) would be more appropriate?

Comment: [womens-bikes] as opposed to womens' saddles and womens' clothing. But I take your point, the tag sounds a bit meta-ish as it is; how about just [women-specific], borrowing a page from Trek? (Whether it's a bike or a pair of shorts or whatever can be covered by other tags.)

Comment: @neil I still like [womens] since it would certainly be [saddles] [womens] and [clothing] [womens]. The bicycle part is implied by the fact of the URL in the address bar...

Comment: I think I prefer [tag:womens-specific] over [tag:womens], since to my ear it implies something closer to the right thing.  Most cycling stuff is unisex, with a few things that are specifically designed for men or women.

Comment: Okay, have retagged those three questions to [women-specific](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women-specific).